# EWMA with a fixed window length in SQL

Tags: sql, vertica, moving-average

I want to calculate exponentially weighted moving average in SQL over a fixed window length. I have some price data, let's say I have a price tick every 30 minutes. I would like to calculate daily EWMA for each tick. i.e., use last 48 data points to calculate the EWMA. I am using Vertica and I know there is a [function](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Analytic/EXPONENTIAL_MOVING_AVERAGEAnalytic.htm) for that. However, this goes over all data, not a window of particular length. I have tried the following:

```
EXPONENTIAL_MOVING_AVERAGE (close_price, 0.5) over (partition by id order by time_dts rows between 48 preceding and current row)
```

but it produces an error:

> [Code: 2045, SQL State: 42P20]  [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: exponential_moving_average must NOT contain WINDOWING clause within its analytic clause

Any help would be appreciated.

I am trying the following code (based on the table from Vertica documentation):

```
select
     *
   , EXPONENTIAL_MOVING_AVERAGE (bid1, 0.5) over (partition by symbol order by time) as ewma
from
     (
        select
               symbol
             , time
             , bid1
          from
               ticker
          ) as a over (partition by symbol order by time rows between 48 preceding and current row)
```

It looks like the function does not support window frames ([link](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AnalyzingData/SQLAnalytics/WindowFraming.htm)). Is there another way to easily calculate the EWMA?

Comment: can you post the error message as well?

Comment: Done, it seems that it is not the intended use of the function.

Comment: yes..the window clause should be specified at the end of the query after `FROM` i guess..that is what the example in the documentation shows at least.

Comment: So how could I apply it in a way that the query calculates the EWMA for each time point in the data while only taking the last 48 observations into account?

Comment: your window clause itself is correct..just use it at the place shown in the documentation.

Comment: I edited the question with the code I as per your suggestions, however, it does not work. Do you have any suggestions why not?